# View docker image layers with recent version of Docker?

Tags: docker

**Updated per feedback**

For versions of Docker equal to or later than 17.03, how would one view the layers of an image?  While I found tons of solutions for earlier Docker systems (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696656/finding-the-layers-and-layer-sizes-for-each-docker-image)), can this still be done now?

I am particularly interested in being able to remove layers one at a time.  I recall reading about this long ago (in Docker time, so that is about 12-18 months!)  However, I lost that reference and can not find it anywhere on the web.  I learned from the first answer below that the intermediate layers are no longer downloaded and report as missing, but if I have the entire image downloaded, is there a way to take it apart one layer at a time?

Comment: What were you using before? What have you tried this time that now isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention "AUFS" but the issue unrelated to storage drivers.

Prior to v1.10.0, docker would download an image along with all of its intermediate layers. Using `docker history <image_id>` you could get the intermediate layer IDs. Then you could explore the `/var/lib/docker/<storage_driver>/` directory to see the changes introduced by each intermediate layer, or you could even start a container from any one of them.

This is no longer the case according to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20131:

> "...We don't pull parent images anymore. You only
> have them if you built the image yourself or if you migrated your old
> image chains."

Note that `docker history` now outputs `<missing>` instead of the image ID for each unavailable intermediate layer.

```
$ docker history ubuntu
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
ccc7a11d65b1        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B                  
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo '...   7B                  
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\...   2.76kB              
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0B                  
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' >...   745B                
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:39d3593ea220e68...   120MB
```

More information here: https://github.com/moby/moby/wiki/Engine-v1.10.0-content-addressability-migration

That being said, if you have access to the Dockerfile **and** the supporting resources that were used to build the image, you can build the image locally (which will save each intermediate layer)

Ubuntu publishes its Dockerfiles here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

So if you wanted to build a 17.10 image for examples you would:

1. Create a build directory
2. Copy the Dockerfile to the build directory.
3. Copy supporting resources to the build directory

> ```
> In this case the dockerfile contains the following command:
> ADD ubuntu-artful-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
> You can find that file with a Google search 
> Note: The ADD command automatically extracts and unzips recognized formats.
> ```

4. cd to the build directory and run `docker build .`

If you don't have access to the Dockerfile, you can try to create one using the output of `docker history --no-trunc` <image_id>` you may run into a couple of issues:

1. You may be missing the supporting resources
2. Layers can be manual modified in which case the output of `docker history` would not tell you the full story