# Why docker rmi command makes multiple items deleted?

Tags: docker

I am learning docker by reading [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/#examples). And for the section about `docker rmi`, I found a confusing example:

> An image pulled by digest has no tag associated with it:
>
> ```
> $ docker images --digests
>
> REPOSITORY                     TAG       DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID        CREATED         SIZE
> localhost:5000/test/busybox    <none>    sha256:cbbf2f9a99b47fc460d422812b6a5adff7dfee951d8fa2e4a98caa0382cfbdbf4986bf8c1536    9 weeks ago     2.43 MB
> ```
>
> To remove an image using its digest:
>
> ```
> $ docker rmi localhost:5000/test/busybox@sha256:cbbf2f9a99b47fc460d422812b6a5adff7dfee951d8fa2e4a98caa0382cfbdbf
> Untagged: localhost:5000/test/busybox@sha256:cbbf2f9a99b47fc460d422812b6a5adff7dfee951d8fa2e4a98caa0382cfbdbf
> Deleted: 4986bf8c15363d1c5d15512d5266f8777bfba4974ac56e3270e7760f6f0a8125
> Deleted: ea13149945cb6b1e746bf28032f02e9b5a793523481a0a18645fc77ad53c4ea2
> Deleted: df7546f9f060a2268024c8a230d8639878585defcc1bc6f79d2728a13957871b
> ```

For the above example, why are there multiple `Deleted` after `docker rmi`? Shouldn't there be only one image being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the command

`docker rmi`

removes all the layers in each image.

If your image has 23 layers, you will see 23

`Deleted`

You can see the layers in an image with the command

`docker history myimage`

See also

[Finding the layers and layer sizes for each Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696656/finding-the-layers-and-layer-sizes-for-each-docker-image)