# Python Docker image is too big

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I am trying to dockerize a Python streamlit app, but the image I built is way to big (1.3GB). Is there any way to minimise the image size?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

COPY ./src ./src

COPY ./deployment/nginx.conf ./deployment/nginx.conf
```

And my requirements.txt file:

```
requests==2.16.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
streamlit==1.10.0
lxml==4.7.1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try `alpine` imgs, very small and minimal

Answer (score 3):

### Inspect image to find culprit

You can look more closely at the docker image to find out which layers are taking up a lot of space. To look at the different layers and their sizes you can use the `docker history` command.
Example:

```
docker history <image-name>
```

- [related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696656/finding-the-layers-and-layer-sizes-for-each-docker-image)
- [docker history documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/)

### Methods to get smaller images

To improve your image size you can look into [multi-staged builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

A really good blog that shows how to realize multi-stage builds in python and create smaller images and faster builds: (blog consists of three articles)

- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/smaller-python-docker-images/
- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/
- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-multi-stage-builds/

Another improvement would be, like @pierpy pointed out, to use the alpine-version of the python image. For example:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
```

See all the image versions [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).